# Python & gdata within Django app: "POST method does not support concurrency"

Tags: python, django, pycharm, gdata

I am trying to use gdata within a Django app to create a directory in my google drive account.  This is the code written within my Django view:

```
def root(request):

   from req_info import email, password
   from gdata.docs.service import DocsService

   print "Creating folder........"
   folder_name = '2015-Q1'
   service_client = DocsService(source='spreadsheet create')
   service_client.ClientLogin(email, password)
   folder = service_client.CreateFolder(folder_name)
```

Authentication occurs without issue, but that last line of code triggers the following error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.7.7
Exception Type: RequestError
Exception Value: {'status': 501, 'body': 'POST method does not support concurrency', 'reason': 'Not Implemented'}
```

I am using the following software:

- Python 2.7.8
- Django 1.7.7
- PyCharm 4.0.5
- gdata 2.0.18
- google-api-python-client 1.4.0 (not sure if relevant)
- [many other packages that I'm not sure are relevant]

What's frustrating is that the exact same code (see below) functions perfectly when I run it in its own, standalone file (not within a Django view).

```
from req_info import email, password
from gdata.docs.service import DocsService

print "Creating folder........"
folder_name = '2015-Q1'
service_client = DocsService(source='spreadsheet create')
service_client.ClientLogin(email, password)
folder = service_client.CreateFolder(folder_name)
```

I run this working code in the same virtual environment and the same PyCharm project as the code that produced the error.  I have tried putting the code within a function in a separate file, and then having the Django view call that function, but the error persists.

I would like to get this code working within my Django app.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall if I got this to work within a Django view, but because Google has since required the use of Oauth 2.0, I had to rework this code anyways.  I think the error had something to do with my simultaneous use of two different packages/clients to access Google Drive.

Here is how I ended up creating the folder using the [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) package:

```
from google_api import get_drive_service_obj, get_file_key_if_exists, insert_folder  

def create_ss():
    drive_client, credentials = get_drive_service_obj()  
    # creating folder if it does not exist  
    folder = get_file_key_if_exists(drive_client, 'foldername')
    if folder:  # if folder exists
        print 'Folder "' + folder_name + '" already exists.'
    else:   # if folder doesn't exist
        print 'Creating folder........"' + folder_name + '".'
        folder = insert_folder(drive_client, folder_name)
```

After this code, I used [a forked version (currently beta) of sheetsync](https://github.com/mbrenig/SheetSync/commit/a7853ed58735d644fcb5a8a3f6e8c6226daee81b) to copy my template spreadsheet and populate the new file with my data.  I then had to import sheetsync *after* the code above to avoid the "concurrency" error.  (I could post the code involving sheetsync here too if folks want, but for now, I don't want to get too far off topic.)